# K-means feature extraction Inception Resnet V2 (Calculate ARI)

Tags: python, keras, k-means

I need to apply K-means to the features extracted from the Inception Resnet v2 network and calculate the adjusted rand index. How do I calculate the latter? Applying the fit_predict function I get a y_pred vector of size 8280576, while y_true is equal to 599.

This is my code:

```
image_size=(150, 150, 3)
model= InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=image_size)   
​   ​
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
​
feature = model.predict(x)
feature = feature.reshape(-1, 1)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
y_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(feature)

from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score
ari = adjusted_rand_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Error:

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [599, 8280576]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rand Index is a function that computes a similarity measure between two clustering. For this computation rand index considers all pairs of samples and counting pairs that are assigned in the similar or different clusters in the predicted and true clustering.

Refer to this:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scikit_learn/scikit_learn_clustering_performance_evaluation.htm

Your y_true and y_pred should be of the same size.

For e.g

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score
   
   y_true = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
   y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3]

adjusted_rand_score(y_true , y_pred )
```

Comment: I know this, I don't understand what I'm wrong with my procedure. In particular, I have to do the k-means on the features extracted from the IRV2 network, the latter correspond to a vector of 1536 dimensions. Then I reshape to pass them to k-means. My test labels (y_true) are equal to 599, now I don't understand where I am wrong in the procedure. Is it wrong to fit features this way?